# asp.net mvc application throw controller exception when application is deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 web application using .net 4.5.1 ,which is working good in local but when I deploy the site to the live server it will throw an exception when I invoke the controller .The exception is only thrown when I put a constructor on the controller.I tested the application by removing the constructor from the controller it will working fine .I cant figure out why this happen .

Here is my controller :

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
  public class TestController : Controller
  {
     private readonly ICountryService _countryService;

     public TestController()
     {
         _countryService=new CountryService();
     }

     // GET: /Test/
     public ActionResult Index()
     {

          var items = _countryService.GetAllCountries();
        return View(items.ToList());
     }
  }
}
```

Here is the exception :

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.] Test.Controllers.TestController..ctor() +74
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.] System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'Test.Controllers.TestController'. Make sure that
>   the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +77
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +66
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +191 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Why this happen when I deploy the website into live server.

Would appreciate any help offered. Let me know if you need any other information to help answer this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Perhaps `Response` is null a that point?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `Response` object is `null`. You can also notice that in the browser, (where the exception occurs) just above the stack trace.

**Edit**: & btw, if you notice, your `HttpContext` object would also be `null`

instead you can try:

```
 var res = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
 res.Write("hi");
```

This works ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a `NullReferenceException` in your constructor. That means you're trying to access an object that's not yet been instantiated. The only object you're accessing is the `Response` object, so the logical conclusion here is that the `Response` member in your controller is null when your controller is instantiated. This is because the context-related data (`Controller.Request`, `Controller.Response`, etc.) does not get populated until the `Initialize` method gets called.

My question is, why would you want to write directly to the `Response` in ASP.NET MVC? It sounds like a bad habit picked up from ASP.NET WebForms.

Here's how to do dependency injection using Ninject:

NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ICountryService>().To<CountryService>();
    // other bindings....
    //...
}
```

TestController.cs

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICountryService _countryService;

    public TestController(ICountryService countryService)
    {
        _countryService = countryService;
    }

    // GET: /Test/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = _countryService.GetAllCountries();
        return View(items.ToList());
    }
```

}

Comment: actually I dont want to use the Response I just want to instantiate my service inside the constructor you can see that on the commented code when uncomment that this exception is thrown

Comment: @Mussammil Why don't you just inject it into the controller using Dependency Injection?

Comment: Porumbo , I am new to asp.net mvc I dont know much about Dependency injection ,If I use dependency injection is this will degrade my application performance ?

Comment: Not at all. And it's dead simple to enable. Just get the Ninject.MVC5 package off NuGet, add your bindings in App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs and change your controller to take an ICountryService as the parameter for its constructor. The pattern you've already set up (with a Service layer and using interfaces) is perfectly suited to DI.

Comment: actually my application is a simple application with a few controllers and few views so using Ninject in my app wont cause any performance lag ? u said add binding in NinjectWebCommon.cs ,Is I need to reference all my service classes here and at runtime the ninject will automatically resolve right ?

Comment: ,what are the other typical objects which register on the NinjectWebCommon.cs other than service

Comment: @Mussammil Anything you want to inject into a Controller via the constructor, as per my example. You can also chain-inject objects, like if your `CountriesService` takes a `CountriesRepository` argument in the constructor, you can have it take an `ICountriesRepository` which you bind to `CountriesRepository` in NinjectWebCommon.cs.